# Running Python Code from PHP

Tags: php, python, beautifulsoup

I have a Python file which uses

```
raw_input()
```

to enter in a URL. I then scrape the website using BeautifulSoup and ask the user a few other questions based on thee data on the website (that I just scraped..)

I wish to convert this command-line tool into a web app.

How would I go about doing this?

```
shell_exec()
```

won't do what I want, because (as far as I know) can't input data from raw_input() through PHP..

Comment: Why use php? -- there are many native Python web frameworks to choose from. CherryPy would seem adequate for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for readline or stdin stream:

With [php://stdin](http://php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.io-streams.php)

```
$fp = fopen("php://stdin","r");
$line = rtrim(fgets($fp, 1024);
```

With [readline](http://php.net/manual/es/book.readline.php):

```
$line = readline("Command: ");
```

Answer (score -1):

I actually created a dnsTools script that would run a perl script similar to how it sounds like what you want to do.  I used shell_exec here is an example of what I did

```
$ip=shell_exec('/usr/bin/perl ./dnstools.pl -ta -h'.$_POST["domain"].' -s@vnsc-lc.sys.gtei.net');
```

Then my script would just return the IP as a string.

Remember:
The output from the executed command or NULL if an error occurred or the command produces no output.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Also, keep in mind the security issues using the command could pose if there is user input.

If shell_exec is turned off you could try using curl to run the command though the web and then still process the results.